# Teamviewer is lowering my Macbook Pro's audio

Tags: audio, macos

Last week I found out when I am in a Team Viewer meeting, Team Viewer is lowering my Macbook Pro's audio. It sets the audio around 10%. When I put it back at 100% it's not the full 100% (for example, it's hardly to hear my friends on Team Speak). When I quit Team Viewer my audio is back at normal.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

**Edit**

I created a video which will explain the problem:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaiYha6XNno

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TeamViewer only ducks the audio device you selected. So if you don't want this feature you should be able to simply select one that you do not need (in the Teamviewer settings, not in macOS).

E.g. I use a `RØDE NT-USB` external microphone as my sound card. I selected `Built-In Line Out/In` as my audio device. Now TeamViewer has no idea what to do. :)

It's an ugly hack but victor's solution didn't work for me.

Comment: I'll try this out the next time I'm using TeamViewer and TeamSpeak at the same time.

Comment: Tried this out today, this solution works aswell. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks this worked! (I first got confused and changed the Mac Output Device, but then realised you meant the option under `Team Viewer > Preferences > Audio`). Interestingly upon connecting with Team Viewer  I still get some lowering of the volume, but it comes back up to normal a second later.

Comment: Sorry I think I might be blind but I can't see the option to change the external microphone? http://imgur.com/a/3Y8X0

Comment: @jackdh, if you want to use a headset for TeamViewer and another application that makes sound you need to put both options on build-in device.

Answer (score 12):

This sounds like the **audio ducking** feature, commonly used by video chatting applications to temporarily lower the volume of other sounds.

To turn it off, go to Applications/Utilities/**VoiceOver Utility.app** > Sound

Uncheck "Enable audio ducking".

Comment: This definitely solves the problem for next runs of TeamViewer. In case you're already experiencing the problem and want to fix your volume level without restarting your computer, just close your currently opened TeamViewer app, and any other app outputting sound, open `Activity Monitor`, search `coreaudiod` and kill it. After you do that volume level will be restored to normal levels.

Comment: Sadly, this is present the the most recent version too. It's quite painful.

Comment: this easter egg i would never have found if not for the teamviewer glitch